# How do I select an XML node with the longest child #text node value with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, textnode

I've used XPath to select the node with the largest integer id value before using this query:

```
//somenode[not(@id <= preceding::somenode/@id) and not(@id <= following::somenode/@id)]
```

I was hoping that I could do something similar like:

```
//entry[not(string-length(child::text()) <= string-length(preceding::entry/child::text())) and not(string-length(child::text()) <= string-length(following::entry/child::text()))]
```

But it returns a bunch of nodes instead of just one.

Sample XML:

```
<xml>
  <entry>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</entry>
  <entry>Nam dignissim mi a massa mattis rutrum eu eget mauris.</entry>
  <entry>Ut at diam a sem scelerisque pretium nec pulvinar purus.</entry>
  <entry>Nunc in nisi nec dolor accumsan suscipit vel a quam.</entry>
  <entry>Nunc suscipit lobortis arcu, nec adipiscing libero bibendum nec.</entry>
  <entry>Aenean eget ipsum et nunc eleifend scelerisque.</entry>
  <entry>In eu magna et diam volutpat molestie.</entry>
  <entry>In volutpat luctus mi, eu laoreet orci dictum vel.</entry>
  <entry>In mattis mi nec magna sodales eu bibendum felis aliquet.</entry>
<!-- etc for 800 more lines or so -->
  <entry>Duis auctor felis id neque gravida ut auctor ipsum ullamcorper.</entry>
  <entry>Sed vel tortor mauris, et aliquet tellus.</entry>
</xml>
```

XPath test: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=1o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The wanted element(s) cannot be selected with a single XPath 1.0 expression**, because in XPath 1.0 it is not possible to apply a function to all selected nodes (`string-length(someNodeSet)` is applied only on the first node of this node-set). Another reason is that in XPath 1.0 it isn't possible to name and reference range variables.

**In XPath 2.0 this is trivial**:

```
/*/entry[not(string-length(.) &lt; /*/entry/string-length(.))]
```

The above selects all `entry` elements the length of whose string value is the maximal one.

```
/*/entry[not(string-length(.) &lt; /*/entry/string-length(.))] [1]
```

The above selects the first (in document order) such `entry` element.

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "/*/entry[not(string-length(.) &lt; /*/entry/string-length(.))]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<xml>
  <entry>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</entry>
  <entry>Nam dignissim mi a massa mattis rutrum eu eget mauris.</entry>
  <entry>Ut at diam a sem scelerisque pretium nec pulvinar purus.</entry>
  <entry>Nunc in nisi nec dolor accumsan suscipit vel a quam.</entry>
  <entry>Nunc suscipit lobortis arcu, nec adipiscing libero bibendum nec.</entry>
  <entry>Aenean eget ipsum et nunc eleifend scelerisque.</entry>
  <entry>In eu magna et diam volutpat molestie.</entry>
  <entry>In volutpat luctus mi, eu laoreet orci dictum vel.</entry>
  <entry>In mattis mi nec magna sodales eu bibendum felis aliquet.</entry>
<!-- etc for 800 more lines or so -->
  <entry>Duis auctor felis id neque gravida ut auctor ipsum ullamcorper.</entry>
  <entry>Sed vel tortor mauris, et aliquet tellus.</entry>
</xml>
```

**selects the `entry` elements (in this case only one) with the maximum string-length and outputs the selected elements**:

```
<entry>Nunc suscipit lobortis arcu, nec adipiscing libero bibendum nec.</entry>
```

Comment: I think you're missing something in that second query, a `[1]` on the end maybe?

Comment: @travis: Good catch -- I am a little off-focus this evening. Corrected.

Comment: +1 - *"(string-length(someNodeSet) is applied only on the first node of this node-set)"* - I made a silly mistake and was then fooled by too-few test cases. This is the best answer.

Comment: @lwburk: Thanks. Yes, the lack of representative test data is one of the biggest problems we have. One way to solve this problem is trying to generalize the initial question and see it in different light.

Comment: I just had a chance to run this query, and it appears to return every node. So the second one just returns the first node in the doc. Using SaxonHE9.3N: 
`C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.3N\bin>query -qs:"/*/entry[string-length(.) >= /*/entry/string-length(.)][1]" -s:sample.xml` returns `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</entry>`

Comment: @travis: Sorry, this must have been an involuntary mistake. I have corrected my answer immediately -- please, try it now.

Comment: This query _does_ seem to work however: 
`C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.3N\bin>query -qs:"//entry[not(string-length(child::text()) <= preceding::entry/string-length(child::text())) and not(string-length(child::text()) <= following::entry/string-length(child::text()))]" -s:sample.xml` 
returns: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry>Nunc suscipit lobortis arcu, nec adipiscing libero bibendum nec.</entry>` 
What's weird is that when I remove the `not()` and reverse the signs, it doesn't work.

Comment: @travis: I personally verified that the updated answer is correct. Added to the answer the XSLT code that uses the XPath 2.0 expression to select the `entry` element(s) with the maximum string-length, and outputs them.

Comment: @travis: You are welcome. Thanks for pointing out this issue. Sometimes, very rarely, I am answering questions late at night or very early in the morning, or hurrying for work and this might have slipped through :)