# Longer node in XPath

Tags: xpath

I'd like to use XPath to retrieve the longer of two nodes.

E.g., if my XML is

```
<record>
   <url1>http://www.google.com</url1>
   <url2>http://www.bing.com</url2>
</record>
```

And I do document.SelectSingleNode(*your XPath here*)

I would expect to get back the url1 node.  If url2 is longer, or there is no url1 node, I'd expect to get back the url2 node.

Seems simple but I'm having trouble figuring it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the maximal number of urls possible?

Comment: Let's assume, for purposes of this example, there are no more than two.  There will be one of three possible cases: url1 but not url2, in which case url1 should be returned; url2 but not url1, in which case url2 should be returned; or both, in which case the longer should win.

Comment: And I guess I should add: I'm using .NET, which means it needs to be XPath 1.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923238/how-do-i-select-an-xml-node-with-the-longest-child-text-node-value-with-xpath

Comment: Sorry, Jiri, that only works for multiple of the same nodes... in this case, the nodes are named differently

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but it is ugly. Cannot you do the comparison outside XPath?

```
record/*[starts-with(name(),'url')
         and string-length(.) > string-length(preceding-sibling::*[1])
         and string-length(.) > string-length(following-sibling::*[1])]/text()
```

Comment: I like the creativity here :)  And this would work for my simplified use case above.  I still wonder, though, if there's any way to get this to work for two nodes that may or may not be in proximity to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
  <xsl:sort select="string-length(.)" data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Even works in XSLT 1.0!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... I need to convert this to an xpath query to be run in conjunction with .NET's SelectNodes method.  How would I do that with your proposed solution

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this was an XPath rather than XSLT question. It's easy enough in XPath 2.0, but if you're stuck with XPath 1.0, then it's not a fun way to spend my Sunday morning...

Answer (score 0):

**Use this single XPath expression**:

```
  /*/*[not(string-length(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)
          >
          string-length()
          )
       ]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/*[not(string-length(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)
              >
              string-length()
              )
         ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<record>
    <url1>http://www.google.com</url1>
    <url2>http://www.bing.com</url2>
</record>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation (the selected element) is copied to the output**:

```
<url1>http://www.google.com</url1>
```