# Spring int-xml:xpath-expression erros with node function

Tags: java, xml, spring, xpath, spring-integration

I used XMLSpy to write the following XPath to determine the longest string length and it works in XMLSpy:

```
string-length(//exception:ElementMessageAbcException/@exceptionMsg[not(string-length(.) < //exception:ElementMessageAbcException/@exceptionMsg/string-length(.))] )
```

But when I put the same string into a xpath-expression in spring integration it errors:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'xpathMaxLengthExceptionMsg': Instantiation of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public static
>   org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpression
>   org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionFactory.createXPathExpression(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
>   throws
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException,org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathParseException]
>   threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathParseException: Could not compile
>   [//exception:MarkitMessageAciException/@exceptionMsg[not(string-length()
>   <
>   //exception:MarkitMessageAciException/@exceptionMsg/string-length())]]
>   to a XPathExpression: null; nested exception is
>   javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException    Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: string-length

```
<int-xml:xpath-expression id="xpathMaxLengthExceptionMsg" expression="//exception:ElementMessageAciException/@exceptionMsg[not(string-length(.) &lt; //exception:ElementMessageAciException/@exceptionMsg/string-length(.))]">
    <map>
        <entry key="pricing" value="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-pricing-aci" />
        <entry key="security" value="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-security-aci" />
        <entry key="tns" value="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-message-aci" />
        <entry key="internalClassification" value="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-internal-classification" />
        <entry key="organization" value="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-organization-aci" />
        <entry key="exception" value="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-message-aci-exception"/>
        <entry key="xsi" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </map>
</int-xml:xpath-expression>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<confirm:ElementMessageAbcConfirm
  confirmTs="2014-10-14T11:43:36.191-05:00"
  correlationId="ORG-1008891250014" numberAccepted="0"
  numberRejected="1" status="exception"
  xmlns:ack="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-message-Abc-ack"
  xmlns:confirm="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-message-Abc-confirm"
  xmlns:event="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/data-source-event"
  xmlns:exception="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-message-Abc-exception"
  xmlns:internalClassification="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-internal-classification"
  xmlns:ns9="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-message-Abc"
  xmlns:organization="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-organization-Abc"
  xmlns:pricing="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-pricing-Abc" xmlns:security="http://www.example.net/imdwrd/schemas/Element-security-Abc">
  <exception:ElementMessageAbcException exceptionCode="1000"
    exceptionMsg="[property]=Organization [message]=Organization information has not changed.  Update request has been cancelled."
    exceptionType="informational" id="385059141722030" type="organization"/>
 <exception:ElementMessageAbcException exceptionCode="1000"
    exceptionMsg="[property]=Organization [message]=Organizatiosn information has not changed.  Update request has been cancelled. longer"
    exceptionType="informational" id="385059141722030" type="organization"/>    
</confirm:ElementMessageAbcConfirm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how XML Spy does work, but I see that this:

```
/@exceptionMsg/string-length(.)
```

is a wrong syntax. `string-length()` is really an xPath `function`, but it isn't a node of your XML.

It isn't clear yet what is your goal, but I hope it should help a bit to go right way.

**UPDATE**

Well, I've figured out what's going on.

You use **XPath 2** ([How do I select an XML node with the longest child #text node value with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923238/how-do-i-select-an-xml-node-with-the-longest-child-text-node-value-with-xpath)), but Java doesn't have that ability by default.

So you should use some other library. [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com) is the best one on the matter.

However you should do this:

```
-Djavax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom=net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl
```

Or specify that System property programmatically.

Comment: I am trying to find the longest exceptionMsg message and get the length of the longest exceptionMsg attribute

Comment: I have also tried the following and it failed also:
string-length(//exception:ElementMessageAbcException/@exceptionMsg[not(string-length() < //exception:ElementMessageAbcException/@exceptionMsg/string-length())] )
string-length without the dot. 
 Got the idea from the following site where it states without any args it is the current node.
**[http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp]**

Comment: Update my answer regarding an ifo about XPath 2