# How to plugin Xpath 2.0 with Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I want to use some xpath functions like upper-case or lower-case available in Xpath 2.

After some netsurfing I found that I can use Jaxen because, it provides implementation of those functions.

The problem I am facing is that, current implementation of spring **XPathExpressionFactory** is directly poitning Jaxp implementation **Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory**.

Please advice how can I upgrade to Jaxon or Saxon library?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496211/spring-int-xmlxpath-expression-erros-with-node-function/26502574#26502574