# Finding the longest cell in a table with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

Building on this topic:
[How do I select an XML node with the longest child #text node value with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923238/how-do-i-select-an-xml-node-with-the-longest-child-text-node-value-with-xpath)
I try to find the longest cell in column 1 of a table. Unfortunately I don't know how many ancestors the table has and there are sometimes several within one text- element which should be treated different.

XML

```
    <text><table cols="3" rows="2">
        <row >
            <cell >first cell first row</cell>
            <cell >second cell first row
            </cell>
            <cell >third cell first row
                    </cell>
        </row>
        <row >
            <cell >first cell second row</cell>
            <cell >this is an incredible long text</cell>
            <cell />
        </row>
    </table>
</text>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="table">
         <xsl:variable name="longest1">
         <xsl:sequence select=
            "/*/table/row/cell[1][not(string-length(.) &lt; /*/table/row/cell[1]/string-length(.))]"/>
         </xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="longest1">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of course should be "first cell second row", as the second column is not processed.
I'm quite sure all I have to do is to fix the /* of this line:

```
<xsl:sequence select=
                "/*/table/row/cell[1][not(string-length(.) &lt; /*/table/row/cell[1]/string-length(.))]"/>
```

But I can't manage to see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are writing a template for the `table` you can simply use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:sequence select="row/cell[1][not(string-length() &lt; current()/row/cell[1]/string-length())]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course another approach would simply be to sort `row/cell[1]` by its string-length and taking the last, done in XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1 using `sort(row/cell[1], function($c) { string-length($c)})[last()]` or in XSLT 2.0 using `<xsl:variable name="sorted-cells" as="element(cell)*"><xsl:perform-sort select="row/cell[1]"><xsl:sort select="string-length()"/></xsl:perform-sort></xsl:variable><xsl:copy-of select="$sorted-cells[last()]"/>`.

Comment: I had to resort to your solution with sorting, because the other one did not work when there are more cells of the same length: <cell>A</cell><cell>A</cell><cell>A</cell><cell>A</cell> would compile as AAA. I imagine it has to do with "lower than" and should be "lower than or equal", but that did not do the trick. The sorting on the other hand worked right away!

Comment: You can use   ` <xsl:sequence select="row/cell[1][not(string-length() &lt; current()/row/cell[1]/string-length())][1]` too.

Comment: Oh, then I must have messed it up when implementing it in my real life-workflow where it produced the error stated. But it works now